# Does OpenGL rendering happen in the rendering pipeline or after the rendering pipeline is complete?

Tags: c++, opengl, pipeline

When does OpenGL render my object to the framebuffer? Does the rendering happen after the rendering pipeline is complete or does it happen in the rendering pipeline (if so, which stage does it render in the pipeline). I recently asked a few people but I got different answers so I am unsure.

Comment: [Rendering Pipeline Overview](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The "rendering pipeline" is the name for the different stages in the OpenGL renderer. Think of it like an assembly line in a factory. Each piece of data goes through multiple steps in the rendering pipeline, and may be combined with other data. When all data is processed, rendering is complete.

You can't even start rendering without a complete rendering pipeline.

"When does OpenGL write to the framebuffer?" is an interesting question. It turns out that normally, when you issue a draw command like `glDrawElements()`, this command is stored in a command buffer and processed at a later point in time. If you just call `glDrawElements()` by itself, you won't know when the rendering happens, but there are ways to find out.

- If you create a **fence** after rendering, you can find out when rendering is complete by querying the fence. See [glClientWaitSync](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClientWaitSync.xhtml)
- If you call `glFinish`, it will wait untill rendering is complete. See [glFinish](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFinish.xhtml).
- Certain commands will wait for rendering to finish as a side effect. For example, [glReadPixels](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadPixels.xhtml), when reading into client memory, will not return until previous rendering operations are complete.